# How to do query in list?

Tags: python

I have a list and dictionary. I want to find the people in dictionary that are matched with the list
For example,

```
people = ['Sam', 'Tom', 'Tony', 'Peter', 'Amy', 'John']

weight_of_people = {'Sam': 100,
                    'Tom': 120,
                    'Cherry': 100,
                    'Jack': 130}
```

In `weight_of_people` only `Sam` and `Tom` exists in the list `people`,
so I want to find out them and add their weight up.

I tried to do this:

```
for weight_of_people in people:
  print(weight_of_people)
```

However, it prints out all of the people in the list

```
Sam
Tom
Tony
Peter
Amy
John
```

How can I fix it and get the sum of weight of Sam and Tom = 220?

Thank you very much

Comment: `for weight_of_people in people` That does not mean "for each person in people that is also in weight_of_people."

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy list comprehension with `sum()`:

```
print(sum([weight for name,weight in weight_of_people.items() if name in people]))
```

Manually, You can try using `in` and loops:

```
people = ['Sam', 'Tom', 'Tony', 'Peter', 'Amy', 'John']

weight_of_people = {'Sam': 100,
                    'Tom': 120,
                    'Cherry': 100,
                    'Jack': 130}

total_weight = 0
for name,weight in weight_of_people.items():
  if name in people:
    total_weight += weight

print(total_weight)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with list comprehension

```
sum([val for key,val in weight_of_people.items() if key in people])
```